# Import TypeScript class dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import

I'm trying to load TypeScript class dynamicaly. But after compilation browser says there is 404 error. Browser tries to load file from the project root. But I need to load it from directory that differs from root. How can I configure it?

[image: Browser can't find file]

`webpack.config.js`:

[image: webpack.config.js]

`tsconfig.json`:

[image: tsconfig.json]

I tried to look for issues in the web. But I found nothing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wepback has `publicPath` configuration that represents destination root inside the project. So dynamically loading modules is going to be looked at this directory.

I found this information here: http://code.fitness/post/2016/02/webpack-public-path-and-hot-reload.html

`webpack.config.js` after updating:

[image: webpack.config.js]